# js and css not loading when hosting next application on GitHub pages

Tags: jekyll, next.js, github-pages

Next.js builds all the static assets in *_next* folder but Github pages does not need to serve those files. I am 404 for static assets.

Example repo: https://github.com/ajaymathur/ajaymathur.github.io
Master branch is hosted and dev branch is for development.

And I guess github pages is not hosting paths starting with **-**. How can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[Add a .nojekyll file](https://github.blog/2009-12-29-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages/) in the root of your pages repo.

This disables Jekyll processing and lets the _next folder (which contains an underscore) get copied to the final website.

Comment: I referenced this answer in [this Next.js GitHub issue.](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/3335)

Comment: Awesome, spent almost a day struggling with this problem, I wasn't aware of this github page jekyll processing!

Answer (score 13):

Simply adding a `.nojekyll` file wasn't enough for me. I had to change the build command to add the file *after* the export to static HTML/CSS/JS like this

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "static": "next build && next export && touch ./out/.nojekyll && echo 'www.mywebsite.com' > ./out/CNAME",
    ...
  },
```

I am also using `gh-pages` to copy the files from the `out` folder to the branch Github Pages will serve, by default the `.nojekyll` file was not copied over. This can be circumvented by setting the `-t` option to `true`

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d out -t true"
    ...
  },
```

After these changes, `npm run static && npm run deploy` should do what you're looking for.

Comment: In 2024, using this as the deploy script seems to work `gh-pages -d out --nojekyll --cname www.mywebsite.com`