# Github pages not resolving links with "_"

Tags: reactjs, next.js, github-pages, relative-path

I just deployed a next.js app to github pages.

I am aware of the classical link referencing problem with relative paths that should include the repo name. (example: https://maximorlov.com/deploying-to-github-pages-dont-forget-to-fix-your-links/)

The issue I'm having is that next generates a path to next specific files on a "_next" folder and also names some of the dependencies such as _sslManifest.js, _buildManifest.js, _app.js, just to name a few.

After days trying to figure out what was going on I tested removing _ from all files/folders names and from the references in the html and css files and the app started working normally.

Even though I found a solution it's actually very time consuming to manually change all names/references everytime I want to upload an alteration to the app. Does anyone have an idea of why this problem is happening and how I might circumvent it?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [js and css not loading when hosting next application on GitHub pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61450307/js-and-css-not-loading-when-hosting-next-application-on-github-pages)?

Comment: thanks a lot @juliomalves, that's exactly what I was looking for!